# regex: practical example with ms modifier

Tags: regex

Is there a practical example with "ms" modifier ? And when use it ?
For example:

`$data ~= /regex/ms`

ThankS

Comment: Is it Perl ? Or do you ask for a C# equivalent ?

Comment: FYI, edited the demo text to make it even more clear. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some sample text.

```
Begin 111
Match this
and This
End

Begin 222
Match this one too
End

Don't match this: Begin 333
Some stuff
End
```

This regex uses the s and m modifiers to match each `Begin...End` block while capturing the digits to Group 1:

```
(?sm)^Begin (\d+).*?End
```

(See the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/xN7lK2) to examine the matches and captures.)

The `s` is important because we want the `.` in `.*?` to match characters on multiple lines. In `s` mode, the `.` can match newline characters, so it grabs characters over several lines.

The `m` is important because we only want the `Begin` to match at the beginning of the line (and the `^` allows us to do that when `m` is set). For instance, we don't want to match a `Begin...End` block in the middle of a line.

**Explain Regex**

```
(?ms)                    # set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                         # matching start and end of line) (with .
                         # matching \n) (case-sensitive) (matching
                         # whitespace and # normally)
^                        # the beginning of a "line"
Begin                    # 'Begin '
(                        # group and capture to \1:
  \d+                    #   digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                         #   the most amount possible))
)                        # end of \1
.*?                      # any character (0 or more times (matching
                         # the least amount possible))
End                      # 'End'
```

Comment: @user3296755 Did this solve your problem? Hey btw, I notice that you haven't yet accepted an answer on StackOverflow. If this answer or another answer solves your problem, please consider "accepting it" by clicking the checkmark on the left, as this is how the reputation system works (accepting an answer gives reputation to both the answerer and to you). Thanks for listening to my 20-second SO rep tutorial, cheers! :)